# React Native JSX tags not matching up

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is kind of bizarre and I'm not sure what is going on here so it would be great if someone else could take a look. Maybe I am missing something. Basically, In my render() there are more tags opening than closing, yet it still builds and works fine. When I try to add in another closing  it fails. I need to add in 2 more tags but they are also failing. What am I missing?

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{
      height: this.state.heightValue
    }}>
      <FadeInView price={this.props.price}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this)}>
          <View style={styles.clickableView}>
            <View style={styles.topRung}>
              <View style={styles.rungLeft}>
                <View style={styles.rankBox}>
                  <Text style={styles.rank}>{this.props.rank}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.line}/>
                <Text style={styles.coin}>{this.props.long}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.rungRight}>
                <Price price={this.props.price}/>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </FadeInView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: it does not look like you have anything wrong. if you are self closing a tag it works the same as closing it with another one. 
Self closing:
<div />
Closing with another tag:
<div></div>

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 self-closing tags

```
<View style={styles.line}/>
...
<Price price={this.props.price}/>
```

`<Tag/>` is "equivalent" to `<Tag></Tag>`